# changing alignment of columns

Tags: tables, alignment, cv

I have the following code from a CV template and currently it has two columns that are left aligned. Is there a way for the second column to be aligned a certain distance (1ex) from the end of the content in the first column, rather than all of column two starting at the same point?

```
\newenvironment{cvskills}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l L{\textwidth * \real{0.9}}}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Your code snippet has several custom commands like `\real`, which means we don't have enough information to help you. Could you please edit your code to [create a minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that we can test for ourselves?

Comment: Additionally, it's hard to tell what you mean by preventing "all of column two [from] starting at the same point," so perhaps it could be useful to edit a screenshot of the problem into your question? If you'd like simply to add some horizontal space between column 1 and 2, you could create an empty column of width 1 ex with nothing inside it.

Comment: Does "for the second column to be aligned a certain distance (1ex) from the end of the content in the first column, rather than all of column two starting at the same point" mean that for each row, the starting point of the material in the right-hand cell should vary according to the width of the contents in the cell on the left? Please advise.